Integral involving a rational function inside a hypergeometric ${}_2F_1$
I want to know if the following integral can be expressed in terms Hypergeometric (or any other rational) functions
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^1 \int_0^1 dr\, dt\,r^{-1-i p} t^{-1-i p} (1-r)^{i p+2 q-1} (1-t)^{i p+2 q-1} \, _2F_1\left(i p+1,2 q;i p+2 q;\frac{e^{-2 \text{$\Delta $t}} (r-1) (t-1) \left(y_1 t-t+1\right) \left(y_2 r-r+1\right)}{r t y_1 y_2}\right)
\end{equation}
Here $p$ takes integer values and $q>0$. One way to do this is to write the power series expansion and then integrate term by term to get the answer but that is how I arrived at this expression. Is there a closed form solution to this integral? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.
